# News Archive in PHP and MYSQL displaying zero results

Tags: php, mysql, archive

I am trying to list all the previous months in which posts have been made and display the number of posts, for example

```
2011
  November (14)
  October (12)
  April (3)
2010
  December (2)

    etc etc
```

The following code is how I am attempting to make this work however it doesnt actually return any results and I cannot seem to wrap my head around why.

```
$sql = "SELECT nid, ndate FROM weaponsnews
    ORDER BY ndate DESC";
$result = $db->query($sql);

$data = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $year = date('Y', strtotime($row['ndate']));
    $month = date('m', strtotime($row['ndate']));

    $data[$year][$month][] = $row;
}
$result->free();

foreach($data as $_year => $_months)
{
    echo $_year. "<br>";
    foreach($_months as $_month => $_entries)
    {
        $mentries = count ($_entries);
        echo $_month. " (" .$mentries. ")";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier if you do the count in the MySQL query. For example:

```
SELECT YEAR(`ndate`) AS 'year', MONTH(`ndate`) AS 'month', COUNT(`nid`) AS 'count'  FROM `weaponsnews ` GROUP BY YEAR(`ndate`), MONTH(`ndate`) DESC
```

This gives you three columns, where the first is the year, the second is the month, and the third is the number of items in that month. You can then easily iterate through this list with foreach. Something like:

```
$data = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[$row['year']][$row['month']] = $row['count'];
}
$result->free();
```

This should give you an array like:

```
$data = array(
    '2001' => array(
        '1' => '83',
        '3' => '102'
    ),
    '2012' => array(
        '6' => '43',
        '9' => '33'
    ),
    '2013' => array(
        '7' => '55'
    )
);
```

You can print the tree by iterating through the array:

```
foreach ($data as $year => $months) {
    echo $year.'<br>';
    foreach ($months as $month => $count) {
            echo $month.'('.$count.')<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok how would change this so I can control how it displays in PHP, for example right now it is displaying the following, `echo "$record[month] - $record[year] ($record[count])";` as `3 - 2012 (1)` which is great I know it is working, but what if I wanted to display it as `March 2012 (1)` I know I can do this with strtotime but where could I put that

Comment: Extended my answer. Haven't tried the code but it should give you an idea how to do it. Let me know if it works.

Comment: I cant actually get the second part of what you edited in to work, I have it pretty close to how I would like it but simply doing this, I just want to chnage the date format it is being displayed in, `$rows = $db->fetch_all_array($sql);
    foreach($rows as $record){
  echo date('F', $record[month]). " " .date('o', $record[year]). "($record[count])";


   }`

Comment: So you want March 2012 (1) instead of the tree? In this case try: echo date('F', mktime(0, 0, 0, $record['month'])).' '.$record['year']. ' ('.$record['count'].')'

Comment: Great That works, I can deal with that, Let's hope the client likes the way that looks, Thanks

Comment: Ok, great! :) Edited my answer in case you would need the original solution. Can't test the while() part because you seem to use a framework, but the rest should work.